# Column cannot be Null

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, exception

I have an error says:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'coursename' cannot be null`

And when I set it Nullable column, it stores whatever text I enter as a null, I tried many collations and didn't work

Here is the code:

```
String coursename = request.getParameter("name");  
String duration = request.getParameter("duration");  

Connection con;
PreparedStatement pst;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentms","root","");
pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into course(coursename,duration)values(?,?)");
pst.setString(1, coursename);
pst.setString(2, duration);
pst.executeUpdate();
out.println("Added sucessfully");
```

Comment: Are you sure `request.getParameter("name")` returns a value? log the values of variables coursename and duration.